# how to create multiple folders in github repository in 1 time

Tags: github

how to create multiple folders in github repository in 1 time I am waiting find Please help me.

I am waiting find Please help me.how to create multiple folders in github repository in 1 time I am waiting find Please help me.

I am waiting find Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

there is no direct way to do that in `GitHub` you can make nested folders, using the `create new files` option and naming them `folder1/folder2/folder3` and so on.

The best thing you can do is to use `git` and use the cmd `mkdir folder1 folder2 folder3` and commit them locally finally pushing them to the remote repository.

Here is a sample code:

```
mkdir folder1 folder2 folder3
git add folder1 folder2 folder3
git commit -m "your commit message"
git push
```